# Insert labels to popup controller from a list in C# WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, list, xaml, popup

If I define a simple `Popup control` in XAML, and I have a list of labels defined in my C# code, how might I go about adding the labels from the list, into my `Popup` via XAML code?

I have been looking around for a while, and haven't quite found what I am looking for, and I know some of you guys / girls will know this from experience.

Adding example.

This is the XAML:

```
<Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=AITokenizerRTB}" Margin="40,10,0,13" Name="termsPopup" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="194" Height="105" IsOpen="True">
```

This is the C# for the `List`:

```
term term1 = new term();
term1.name = "One";

term term2 = new term();
term2.name = "Two";

term term3 = new term();
term3.name = "Three";

term term4 = new term();
term4.name = "Four";

term term5 = new term();
term5.name = "Five";

term term6 = new term();
term6.name = "Six";

list.Add(term1);
list.Add(term2);
list.Add(term3);
list.Add(term4);
list.Add(term5);
list.Add(term6);
```

I would like to add labels, which say:

> One
>
> Two
>
> Three
>
> Four
>
> Five
>
> Six

Comment: can you provide us a sample of the code that you already have currently..? also is your List something like this `List<Label>` meaning you would replace `Label` with your actual `Label Instance`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

C#

```
ObservableCollection<term> _myList = new ObservableCollection<term>();
public ObservableCollection<term> MyList{get{return _myList;}}
```

XAML

```
    <Popup Name="popup" IsOpen="True">
        <ItemsControl Name="myContainer" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyList}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Path=name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Popup>
```

whenever you add something to `MyList` it shows up in `Popup`.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, I just tried this but nothing seems to get added into the actual popup... is appears to remain blank :(

Comment: @Slippy Can you share some of your code? You might be missing something.

Comment: Got this to work with some messing around using templates. Thanks :)